# Recursively parse directory names and add a string if it is not found in the directory name

Tags: command-line

I would like to parse my FLAC music directory like this:

- recursively check DIRECTORY names only
- if the directory name does not contain the string "FLAC" or "flac", add " [FLAC]" at the end of the directory name.

This looks like it correctly finds the directories NOT containing the "FLAC" string:

```
find . -type d -not -iname '*flac*'
```

How can I then append " [FLAC]" to each of the directory names?

Comment: Use at your own risk. Add `-exec mv {} {}'[FLAC]' \;` to your find command. You will likely have to play with various quotations to handle appending a string containing a space and to manage any directory names containing spaces, new lines, tabs, etc. The `[]` characters might also give you problems depending on your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -not -iname '*flac*' -execdir echo mv -n -- '{}' '{} [FLAC]' \;
```

(remove the `echo` only after THOROUGH testing).

The `-depth` option specifies a depth first search, which avoids the case where it tries to rename a child whose ancestor has already been renamed. The `-mindepth 1` stops it from trying to add  `[FLAC]` to the current directory, `.`

The exact quoting of the replacement string is a matter of personal preference - `... {} {}\ \[FLAC\]` or `... {} {}' [FLAC]'` would work equally well.

Note that while GNU `find` replaces `{}` everywhere (not just where it occurs alone), other implementations might not - in that case you'd need to do something like

```
... -execdir sh -c 'for d; do echo mv -n -- "$d" "$d [FLAC]"; done' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: This solved my problem, and your explanation is very useful. Much appreciated.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script to handle the direcrory names, and use `find` piped to `xargs` to feed the directory names to the script. Something like:

```
find . -type d -print0 | \
    xargs -0 $HOME/bin/waltscript
```

And do your checking and renaming in `$HOME/bin/waltscript`.